# How many random characters must an unguessable string contain?

Tags: brute-force, random

I want to add a suffix to my URLs that makes them distinctive and therefore only findable by a person who knows that suffix. I considered using a UUID or hash, but these are usually very long. However, I want the suffixes to be as short as possible and still not be guessable. So the question is, what is the **minimum number** of random characters (uppercase and lowercase letters only) that the suffix should consist of?

It is easy to calculate the number of possible combinations by exponentiating the number of possible letters (26*2=52) with the length of the suffix. For suffixes of length 5, 6, 7, 8 and 9 this would be the following possible combinations:

```
52^5 =        380,204,032
52^6 =     19,770,609,664
52^7 =  1,028,071,702,528
52^8 = 53,459,728,531,456
52^9 =           ~2,78e15
```

Are there any best practices which number of combinations is considered "guessing safe"?

**Note:**

- It is a web server so I can control the rate-limit (offline brute-forcing is not an issue)
- There will probably never be more than 10,000,000 suffixed URLs
- Guessing an URL correctly could reveal confidential, but annonymized data of little worth

Comment: What's the payoff for guessing the suffix correctly? 100000 bitcoins? The point is that the value of the data being protected informs the choices of how to protect it.

Comment: When I am pentesting, I don't even start brute forcing if the target has more than 8 chars. Most of the time, it is not worth it. However @President James K. Polk has a good point: 'what is the gain from a successful attack' is a valid question.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk I added it to the question, although your comments kind of answer the question for me already :)

Comment: Why are short strings a value?

Comment: @schroeder I want the links to be shareable without filling up a whole chat box^^

Comment: So, why not use URL shorteners as a guide? https://bit.ly/3pLqTeO (7 chars, a-zA-Z0-9) And you have another control: brute-force protection. If your server is experiencing a lot of false requests, you can block those IPs. So, your strings do not need to be so long.

Comment: @schroeder Nice idea actually, but I still want to represent my brand (aka the domain) in the URLs

Comment: I'm not suggesting using a URL shortening service, but use their URL strings as a guide. (Plus, URL shortening services allow you to add your own domain)

Comment: But these services aren't aiming at URLs being unguessable, do they?

Comment: Let's say you decide to use strings of 8 chars long. If you have 10,000,000 different URLs, the possibility of someone guessing 1 of them would be 1 in 5,345,972. Is that good enough for you?

Comment: @NoahBroyles Yes, that sounds sufficient. I decided to use eight characters, but with numbers, so the probability is even much lower.